# Storing bechamel sauce

Tags: storage-method, sauce, bechamel

Is storing a Bechamel Sauce in the fridge for up to week ok? Will it curdle or otherwise go bad? I love eating Croque Monsieurs for dinner and adding a bit of Bechamel is awesome but I would rather make a batch once and then use it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store béchamel for 4-5 days safely in the refrigerator.  Cool the unused portion as quickly as possible after the sauce is finished and make sure to place a piece of cling film directly in contact with the surface of the sauce prior to refrigerating it so that it doesn't form a skin and slows down oxidation.  Do not freeze the sauce as it will likely break the emulsion.

Another way to make it easier to make your nightly béchamel would be to pre-make a larger batch of roux and freeze it in portions for later use in sauce.

Comment: In the Bouchon cookbook, Keller reports that you can refrigerate sauce mornay (béchamel with cheese added) for "a week" (which I would assume to be 7 days, but could be 5).  He also recommends the cling wrap and suggests thinning it out with cream if necessary.

Comment: Don't use plastic directly -- although formulas have been changed  in response to health concerns, certain plasticizers which are not good for you (and which tend to be fat-soluble) can leach into the sauce. Use wax or parchment paper.

Comment: I don't know if it's necessary to freeze the roux. It'll keep for a couple of weeks, [I think](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21146/how-long-will-roux-keep).

Comment: This is an old post, but I make this sauce for Mac and Cheese, and it's been in the fridge for a week or so before.  What exactly happens to the sauce?  Are you saying it's bad to store after a week?  Does it go bad/harmful for consumption, or it just starts breaking down and the sauce isn't the same:?  I haven't really a issue.

@JoshCaswell Any sources for this claim?  I heard plasticizers only leech when dealing with heat, i.e., microwave or oven.

Are you saying this isn't true and that any fatty foods should not be used with plastic wrap?  I also heard the stretchy plastics are the issue.

Comment: @XaolingBao Both claims are speculation. I doubt they analysed several bechamel samples under a microscope samples after different days or something like that.